# Has anyone used JanRain / RPX to enable users multiple login options (e.g. Google, Twitter, Facebook, etc)?

Tags: authentication, facebook, janrain

I'm debating whether to consider using a product like this to provide my users with multiple login options or to build/maintain this myself internally.  What are the pros of this product/service?  What do you see as the major arguments NOT to use this project/service?

Comment: The huge question is: who are the competitors to Janrain? This is what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to build and manage relationships with all the ID providers and keep up to date on new services as the IDPs role them out, keep up with changes in OpenID, OAuth, Portable Contacts, Microformats, Activity Streams, as well as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, LiveID proprietary formats, you might want to outsource this capability.  If you also want integrated activity-based social publishing to Facebook, MySpace, Yahoo, Twitter, and soon Google, Microsoft, and LinkedIn, another reason to outsource it.  You can see some of Janrain's customers at http://www.janrain.com/customers.  Additionally RPX is integrated with UserVoice, GetSatisfaction, KickApps, WetPaint, Viewpoints, and other SaaS web technology solutions.

Comment: One huge problem with Janrain is that it is one of those annoying companies which, simply, does not state the price of the service on the web page.  You have to annoyingly phone them so they can negotiate a price. We have one client (two million users on the app) and the boss at the client just immediately said "forget that, i don't deal with nonsense like that" which is unfortunate since, otherwise, Janrain seems very awesome. But it is a non-starter if they have a 1950s business model.